# Does FontAwesome's fa-pulse have a unicode value?

Tags: sass, font-awesome

I have a `.scss` page that includes the following:

```css
.actiontitle{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: lighten($primary,20);

  &.saving::before {
    content: "\f110"; //spinner
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to make the spinner pulse.  Font Awesome has another class (`fa-pulse`) that does this, but I'm not finding any kind of unicode value for `fa-pulse` like I can for `fa-spin`.

**Does `fa-pulse` have a unicode character that can be used in CSS?**

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question of if there is a unicode character for `fa-spin`, but I was able to somewhat accomplish what I want with the following:

```css
&.saving::before {
  content: "\f110";
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  animation: fa-spin 1s steps(8) infinite;
}
```